# Insert and return value in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to insert and return the primary key in one query , is it possible ?
the reason is that primary key is autoincrement so i don't know what it is.

```
insert into Person(name) values ('Radouane')
```

Select PersonId : the current id that i inserted.

Thanks,

Comment: How does the primary key get the id ? using a `sequence` or by `identity` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RETURNING INTO`clause is what you need:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  l_id person.PersonId%type;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO person ( name ) VALUES ( 'Radouane' ) 
    RETURNING id INTO l_id;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Returning ID value is : '||l_id );
END;
/
```

Replace "id" with your primary key column and "l_id" with the variable you want to put the value in.

There are plenty of examples available on the internet. Note that is is limited to PL/SQL, it cannot be used in SQL.

Comment: i got 00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"

Comment: You should add that this is only possible in PL/SQL, not in SQL

Comment: yeah i'm using oracle, but i'm still getting the same error "missing keyword"

Comment: @user2848242 pl/sql is the procedural language in oracle (functions, triggers, proceduces, anonymous blocks), sql is the query language. You cannot insert and query in a single sql statement in Oracle, but you can insert and and use that value for another operation within the same transaction in pl/sql - that is what the return into is for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example:

```
DECLARE
   strlen   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO myemp(ename) values('emp-name')
   RETURNING LENGTH(ename) INTO strlen;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(strlen);
END;
/
```